# Object distortion while passing from REST service to Spring app

Tags: spring, rest

I've got strange problem and I hope you will to help me to solve it.
I try to pass list of objects, where each object contains LocalDate parameter (JodaTime library) from test service to my controller.

**This is method from my service. It returns list of objects. Look at the dates printed out in the loop.**

```
@RequestMapping("/getListaRecept")
@ResponseBody
public ListaRecept sendAnswer(){
    ListaRecept listaReceptFiltered = prescriptionCreator.createListaRecept();

    for(Recepta r : listaReceptFiltered.getListaRecept()){
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
    return listaReceptFiltered;
}
```

**Dates are correct**

```
Recepta{id=3, nazwa='nurofen', status=NOT_REALIZED, date=2017-07-27}
Recepta{id=1, nazwa='ibuprom', status=ANNULED, date=2014-12-25}
Recepta{id=2, nazwa='apap', status=REALIZED, date=2016-08-18}
```

**And now I'm invoking this method from my SpringBoot app using restTemplate. And then received list is printed out**

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public SgrService2(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    this.restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-16")));
}

public ListaRecept getList() {
    for(Recepta r : this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8090/getListaRecept", 
            ListaRecept.class).getListaRecept()){
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8090/getListaRecept", 
            ListaRecept.class);
}
```

**As you can see all dates were replaced with current date :/**

```
Recepta{id=3, nazwa='nurofen', status=NOT_REALIZED, date=2017-09-30}
Recepta{id=1, nazwa='ibuprom', status=ANNULED, date=2017-09-30}
Recepta{id=2, nazwa='apap', status=REALIZED, date=2017-09-30}
```

I have no idea what is going on... 
Here you have pom dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `.getListaRecept()` what's that method doing? It seems its the culprit?

Comment: It is just getter . I've got ListaRecept class containing only one filed - ArrayList wich name is "listaRecept"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong jackson module, instead of jsr310 (which I guess is for Java 8 date types), try using the artifact `jackson-datatype-joda` and register the module `JodaModule`.